Ads does not show on video when he is full screen
I have video player on my website which shows Google Ads. For some reason the ads not showing when the video is full screen, the ads are showing in the background and you can hear them, but in order to see them you need to put:
display: none

on them. what am I missing? here`s the code for player:
<div id="v-container" style="position: relative;">
<video id="video-element"
       class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
       poster="<%= videoImageURL %>"
       controls
       preload="auto"
       height="400"
        <%= isMuted ? "muted" : ""%>>
    <source src="<%= videoURL %>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="video-cover" class="video-cover" style="display: none;" onclick="document.getElementById('video-element').play()">
    <img src="<%= coverUrl %>>">
</div>
<div id="video-actions" class="video-actions" style="display: none">
    <span class="video-button">
       <span id="video-next-button" class="next-button" style="display: none;"></span>
       <span id="video-next-counter" class="counter" style="display: none;">3</span>
    </span>
</div>
<div id="ad-container" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js"></script>

thanks in advance.
